# django "MyModel.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: python, django

helloo

I have in DJANGO app two functions where I want to work in my views.py  the second function need the output from the first function to work.

my views.py(before) :

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def app_details(request,slug):
        if request.method == "POST":
            b = request.user.id
            test = request.POST.get('index')
            test_path_export=test+'add/path'
            my_task_name(test,test_path_export)
            save_alg(request.user,test_path_export)
        return render(request, 'details.html'...............................
```

my_function_name.py

```
def my_function_name(input1,output1):
     ..................................
     ..................................
```

myalg.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def save_alg(user_id,input1):
    instance = MyModel.objects.create(user=user_id, field1=input1)
     ..................................
     ..................................
    instance.save()
```

and all work functions(my_task_name,save_alg) works fine ...

now I want to create one function from this two functions to work in the some function because I want to add async tasks using celery in the future and if I have one function is very easy to use `.delay`.

I change my_function_name.py to:

```
def my_function_name(user_id,input1,output1):
     ..................................
     ..................................
    return save_alg(user_id,output1)
```

and second try to

```
def my_function_name(user_id,input1,output1):
     ..................................
     ..................................
    save_alg(user_id,output1)
```

and in my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def app_details(request,slug):
        if request.method == "POST":
            b = request.user.id
            test = request.POST.get('index')
            test_path_export=test+'add/path'
            my_task_name(request.user,test,test_path_export)
        return render(request, 'details.html'...............................
```

error message in line `instance = MyModel.objects.create(user=user_id, field1=input1)` :

```
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "28": "MyModel.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

I have add :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import user
```

in all python files.

any idea how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`user=foo` assumes that `foo` is itself an instance of a `User` object. You're passing in a string that's supposed to be the user's ID:

```
instance = MyModel.objects.create(user_id=user_id, field1=input1)
                                      ^^^
```

Either pass around a `User` object or change `user=` to `user_id=`.

Comment: but in my `models.py` I have `user` field and not `user_id `. `user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)` and in the first test work fine using user.

Comment: @Mar: Like I said, either do `my_user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)` and then pass `user=my_user`, or just do `user_id=user_id`. The first one requires a second database hit while the second one does not.

Comment: you are correct problem solve by Mr.  Blender thnx you